# StructureMap: How to inject IUser into constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, iprincipal, structuremap3

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 website and I would like to access current user info from my own class (that has no idea of http context). How can I inject it into that class?

Apparently, I can't even inject `IUser` into a MVC controller either. It throws this error.

> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

I don't want to pass the user info manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must create a controller factory like

```
public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Page not found: {0}", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as Controller;
    }
}
```

and in golobal.asax in Application_start() add

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
x.For<IUserService>().Use<UserService>();
}
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyControllerFactory());
```

and in your controller

```
public class UserController:Controller{
public ContractController(IUserService userService){}
}
```

now IUserService injected in your controller